# Azure resource mover failed, but resources were moved

Tags: azure, azure-migrate

I moved around 50 resources (includes DB, website, etc.) from one subscription to another subscription. Official status after moving was failed with error message:
*All move in provider succeeded. However, the batch move job failed. The correlation id is...*

However resources seems to work fine and they are in new subscription. Should I concern of something?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of resources you moved, you could indeed have side effects.

You might have missed some components that are hidden - you can unhide by clicking this box in the portal or by querying Azure Graph.

[image]

Also, Microsoft deploys additional components in their backbone that you do not have control on (like network related policies for example). The migration can fail in the back while depicting a false success on your end. You should refer to [move operations - supported services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources) first, and most probably raise a case to check that everything went fine if all services you moved are supposed to be supported.